# How can I make a small logo on my social cards with <meta> tags?

Tags: html, preview, head

So I made a "social card" with  tags, but its missing something

[image: What my website preview looks like]

I want it to look like these:

[image: What I want it to look like]

Here is my code:

My HTML:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <meta name="keywords" content="Learn, Maths, Mathmatics, Story, School, Homework, Learning, Education, fun"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Summit" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://summit.tahaparacha1.repl.co/" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Home | Summit" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="images/Logo.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="The best online, free mathmatics learning platform! Summit allows you to learn mathmatics whenever you want and wherever you are! Simply click Start learning to unlock a massive library off free education; Enjoy!"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#fcbf49" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fcbf49" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/Logo.png">
  </head>
```

Comment: You should specify the full URL, i.e.: `https://summit.tahaparacha1.repl.co/images/Logo.png`

Comment: Like this: 

```<meta property="og:image" content="https://summit.tahaparacha1.repl.co/images/Logo.png" />
```

Comment: Yes, like this.

Comment: Does it update immediately?

Comment: Probably not. I am pretty sure thats cached and may take a while

Comment: alright! thanks for the help! Btw just a quick question. What do you call those embed thingys, are they website previews?

Comment: @Baha They are called Open Graph Meta Tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify an absolute URI instead of a relative one for the `og:image` meta property. In addition you should add a `twitter:card` meta tag for compability.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Summit</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="Learn, Maths, Mathmatics, Story, School, Homework, Learning, Education, fun"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Summit" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://summit.tahaparacha1.repl.co/" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Home | Summit" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://summit.tahaparacha1.repl.co/images/Logo.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="The best online, free mathmatics learning platform! Summit allows you to learn mathmatics whenever you want and wherever you are! Simply click Start learning to unlock a massive library off free education; Enjoy!"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#fcbf49" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fcbf49" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/Logo.png">

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
</head>
```

Comment: Alright, Thank You!

Answer (score -2):

try with this example of url image:

"~/Images/Siereves.ico"

[image]

Comment: That is not an answer for the question.

Comment: The example was only add --> ~/ at the beginnig --> "~/images/Logo.png"